# What to do about "system running in low-graphics mode"?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

My Dell which was 5 years old suddenly karked it and I had the "low graphics" black screen and useless dialogue box.

As I believed it was a dead graphics card I went out and bought a brand new machine.  I put aside the new machine and tried again in vain to open the Dell.  I eventually got to the command line via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.  I logged into my account from there, and simply started a series of `sudo apt-get remove` of various softwares that I knew were installed on my PC (software without any great consequence like Google earth, tweak, Skype etc).

Lo and behold after a `sudo reboot` my computer was fine again!  So now I have 2 computers.  BUT one week after buying the other one and installing 12.04 because I love Ubuntu, the SAME PROBLEM arrived!

I once again deleted Google earth, Skype, and did a `sudo reboot` and everything worked as before.  I think there is a bug or something in 12.04 as this problem has never arisen with any other versions of Ubuntu.